# How to move TempDB to RAM in SQL Server 2005 / 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

On the internet I found instructions to move SQL Server's TempDB to RAM but unfortunately those instructions don't seem to work for 2005 or 2008 anymore because the menu entries Microsoft describes in the article don't exist.
How is it done in version 2005 and 2008?

Here are the non-working instructions I found:

> Configure tempdb to temporarily reside
>   in RAM. To do this, perform the
>   following steps:
>
> Right-click the server name and click Configure on the shortcut menu.
>   Alternatively, you can click the
>   Server menu, point to SQL Server, and
>   then click Configure. Click the
>   Configuration tab. Scroll down until
>   you see the "tempdb in RAM (MB)"
>   configuration option. In the Current
>   column, type a number of megabytes of
>   RAM to allocate to tempdb (for
>   example, 2). This will only be
>   temporary. Then click OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can no longer move tempdb to RAM with SQL Server configuration. 
To achieve this you would need to use some sort of [RamDisk](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?63273-%2a-Windows-7-Ultimate-Tweaks-amp-Utilities-%2a&s=b59bc256a9d14eea67e0de750a42afb2&p=442160#post442160) tool. In my experience the results are rather disappointing. You are better off leaving the memory available to SQL Server so it can decide on it's own what to cache.

Once you installed the ramdisk you can move your tempdb to the new disk

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE tempdb 
MODIFY FILE (NAME = tempdev, FILENAME = 'x:\tempdb.mdf');
GO
ALTER DATABASE  tempdb 
MODIFY FILE (NAME = templog, FILENAME = 'X:\templog.ldf');
```

Where X: would be the drive letter for the RamDisk

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to do that. I justr stumbled about the option to have it in RAM but as you say it is no longer supported, I don't mess around with it. But an option would be to have temp DB on a disk as fast as possible I guess. A RAID with write cache off seems to have bad impact on performance.

Comment: tempdb should always be located on RAID 1+0. Write caching off is bad for performance and should not be done for tempdb. On the disks for your real database write caching should be off if it is not battery backed.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem you're trying to solve.

TempDB behaves like any other database with regard to memory. It may however become a bottleneck if your workload is tempdb heavy causing and all the temp objects can't reside in memory and have to be flushed to disk.

Comment: I just want to try something out. I read about the possibility of explictely moving tempDB into RAM and I'm curious what (side) effects it would have. So do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Way waaay back, when 1M was a LOT of memory (DOS could only readily access the first 640k), I recall there being software that could create a virtual disk in that high memory--one that you would map as a physical drive. And then hard drives came along, and the market for virtual drives dried up. Presumably, modern-day tools and utilities must exist that provide the same functionality. If so, you could configure a server with a virtual drive, then configure SQL to create the tempdb files on this drive. Of course, more things could go wrong with this than with conventional drives, so I'd think long and hard before trying it.

Answer (score 0):

www.amd.com/ramdisk has a great ramdisk.. I am currently able to sustain reads of close to 10 gigabytes per second.. which obviously does great things for SQL Server bottlenecks.

I was even able to move SSAS cubes to the Ramdisk, and most of my queries went down from 60ms down to under 1ms.

I use this for REAL DATABASES not just tempdb!!!

Answer (score 0):

this is an old topic but still showed up in my search.

So I am sharing the up-to-date answer.

below script works on MSSQL 2019:

ALTER SERVER CONFIGURATION SET MEMORY_OPTIMIZED TEMPDB_METADATA = ON;